# Apply function to pairs of columns in Julia

Tags: arrays, loops, functional-programming, julia

I have a pair of matrices, say `Ws, Xs`, of equal dimension and a function `myFunc(w, x)` which takes two vectors as input. I want to apply this function to pairs of columns (think of it as `zip`-ing the columns) and mapping this function to them.

Is there a non-iterative way to do this? If there were *only two* columns in each of `Ws, Xs`, I can do

```
allCols = permutedims(reshape(hcat(Ws, Xs), d, 2), [1, 3, 2])
mapslices(x -> myFunc(x[:, 1], x[:, 2]), allCols, dims=[1, 2])
```

but I'm having trouble moving to an arbitrary number of columns.

**Edit**: using `vcat` and the correct dimensions seems to fix this:

```
# assume d is column size
wxArray = reshape(vcat(Ws, Xs), 2, d)  # group pairs of columns together
mapslices(x -> myFunc(x[:, 1], x[:, 2]), wxArray, dims=[1,2])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eachcol` function like this (I give three ways just to show different possible approaches but `eachcol` is crucial in all of them):

```
julia> Ws = rand(2,3)
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.164036  0.233236  0.937968
 0.724233  0.102248  0.55047

julia> Xs = rand(2,3)
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0493071  0.735849  0.643352
 0.909295   0.276808  0.396145

julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> dot.(eachcol(Ws), eachcol(Xs))
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.6666296397421881
 0.19992972241709792
 0.8215096642236619

julia> dot.(eachcol.((Ws, Xs))...)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.6666296397421881
 0.19992972241709792
 0.8215096642236619

julia> map(dot, eachcol(Ws), eachcol(Xs))
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.6666296397421881
 0.19992972241709792
 0.8215096642236619
```

This requires Julia 1.1.

#### EDIT

If you are on Julia 1.0 and do want to avoid iteration while not mind some extra allocations (the solution above avoids allocations) you can also use `cat` function (which is a bit simpler than your approach I think):

```
julia> Ws = rand(2,3)
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.975749  0.660932  0.391192
 0.619872  0.278402  0.799096

julia> Xs = rand(2,3)
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0326003  0.272455  0.713046
 0.389058   0.886105  0.950822

julia> mapslices(x -> (x[:,1], x[:,2]), cat(Ws, Xs; dims=3), dims=[1,3])[1,:,1]
3-element Array{Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}},1}:
 ([0.975749, 0.619872], [0.0326003, 0.389058])
 ([0.660932, 0.278402], [0.272455, 0.886105])
 ([0.391192, 0.799096], [0.713046, 0.950822])
```

of course you can also simply do this:

```
julia> map(i -> (Ws[:,i], Xs[:,i]), axes(Ws, 2))
3-element Array{Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}},1}:
 ([0.975749, 0.619872], [0.0326003, 0.389058])
 ([0.660932, 0.278402], [0.272455, 0.886105])
 ([0.391192, 0.799096], [0.713046, 0.950822])
```

or more fancy:

```
julia> (i -> (Ws[:,i], Xs[:,i])).(axes(Ws, 2))
3-element Array{Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}},1}:
 ([0.975749, 0.619872], [0.0326003, 0.389058])
 ([0.660932, 0.278402], [0.272455, 0.886105])
 ([0.391192, 0.799096], [0.713046, 0.950822])
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't avoid Julia 1.0 for now, but this looks much cleaner that playing around with `reshape` stuff.